# 3D Geometry Object Library?

Tags: javascript, 3d

I'm wanting to find a javascript library that will create images of simple 3D shapes like the ones shown below.

The key is that I want to be able to specify certain attributes of the shapes.  So, take a cylinder, for example.  I'd want to tell the library the radius and the height and have it create the cylinder for me.

Does anyone know of something that can do this?

[image: Examples of shapes I'd want to create.]

Comment: Look at Canvas, I have seen a demo where Canvas was running and the shapes even had video layered on to the shapes you have here.

Comment: You mean <canvas>?  Or is that the name of some library?

Comment: I do mean the '<canvas>' and some of the html5, I saw some great demos, I did try to find a link but the link was not informative but [here](http://prezi.com/yvniyyedhad7/interactive-film-engine/?utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=copy) and also [this] (http://cssdeck.com/labs/html5-canvas-3d-cubes) seems more useful.